# Writing separate file as per code in contents of file

Tags: python, group-by

I have a huge file which has four different columns. One of the column has codes such as 'AB','BC', 'CA' and so on. I would like to create separate file for each code. Example file_AB with all four fields but having code field of only 'AB'. 
I would like to do using python.

```
with open("C:/Users/Desktop/JesseData/fileread.txt") as f1:
    with open("C:/Users/Desktop/JesseData/fileout.txt") as f2:
        for line in f1:
            if fourth_attribute == 'CA':
              f2.write(line)
```

Comment: Why don't you give it a try and post some code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to give you a full code to do this, but here's a start:

**Step 1: Read the file**

If your file is huge, you will want to read it in chunks.  To do this, you can keep track of a number of lines you've read in each chunk, and then when that iterator reaches a limit, dump the data to your separate files.  Something like:

```
with open("raw_data.txt", 'r') as f:
    i = 0
    data = []
    for line if f:
        data.append(line)  #do some formatting here
        i += 1
        if i >= THRESHOLD:
             data_dump(data)
             data = []
             i = 0
```

This way, you prevent having the entire file in memory all at once.

**Step 2: Group your data**

In your `data_dump` function, you will want to group the data.  This can be most easily accomplished with [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).  This function takes an iterable and a key, then returns an iterator divided into groups.  If your data is formatted where each line is a list of values in that row, and your key is the first entry, your grouping may look like this:

```
groups = itertools.groupby(data, key = lambda x: x[0])
```

Note that `groupby()` expects a sorted data set, so you will need to sort the data with the same key function.  Below is a simple example of `groupby`

```
>>> lst = [[1, 2,3],[1,4,5],[2,45,65]]
>>> import itertools
>>> groups = itertools.groupby(lst, key = lambda x: x[0])
>>> 
>>> for g in groups:
...     print g[0], list(g[1])
...
1 [[1, 2, 3], [1, 4, 5]]
2 [[2, 45, 65]]
```

**Step 3: Write the data**

Once your data is grouped, you can just loop through the groups, and append the data to the corresponding output file. I'd recommend keeping a dictionary of file handles:

```
d = {"AB": open("AB.txt", 'a'), "BC", ....}
```

This way you can easily write to the correct file when you loop through all of your loops

Comment: thank you so much fo such a detailed explanation. My file is not a list, rather it contains attributes separated by ";". So, is there a way I could group using delimiter.